# Silverlight {Binding} won't access class members

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7, binding

I have a `DataTemplate` for ListBoxItem that (should be) fairly simple, and just access via `{Binding}` the properties of my class.

Below is my class and code that creates a simple (dummy) ItemsSource of the ListBox.

```
public class ChatMessage
{
    public string Message = "Testing Message";
    public DateTime DateReceived = new DateTime(2011, 07, 16, 14, 00, 05);

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return Message;
    }
}

// ....

// Dummy Data
ObservableCollection<ChatMessage> chatItems = new ObservableCollection<ChatMessage>();
for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
    chatItems.Add(new ChatMessage());
lbMessages.ItemsSource = chatItems;
```

Here's my DataTemplate..

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="ChatItemListBox">
    <Grid Width="362">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="26" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Message}" />
        <TextBlock Grid.Row="1"Text="{Binding DateReceived}"/>
    </Grid>
</DataTemplate>
```

For some reason both `TextBlock`s are completely empty. However, if I change for example `{Binding Message}` to just `{Binding}` it will call ToString and show the message.

I know I must be missing something very simple..

Just in case it matters, the ListBox is defined as below:

```
<ListBox x:Name="lbMessages" Margin="0,8,0,72" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ChatItemListBox}"/>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use properties, not fields.

```
public class ChatMessage
{
    public string Message { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateReceived { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return Message;
    }

    public ChatMessage()
    {
        Message = "Testing Message";
        DateReceived = new DateTime(2011, 07, 16, 14, 00, 05);
    }
}
```

This is because binding is using reflection for non-DependencyProperties, and doesn't look for fields.

(This advice would solve the problem for WPF, but Silverlight may have some additional quirks.)

Comment: You're exactly right, I've just read that you can't perform databinding on fields. Thank you for making me feel stupid and fixing my hours of misery ;-) (Will accept in 5 minutes, when I am able to!)